# object of type ‘closure’ is not subsettable in R Shiny leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, flexdashboard

I would like to add slider input data to my map through loop function. When I change the slider input value it will generate map based on filtered data. Here is my code

````
---
title: "EU Site Selection -Implemented by: UNOPS"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet.extras)

df <- read_csv("data.csv")


```
Column {.sidebar data-width=150}
-------------------------------------
```{r}
````

Here I added Two variables to Slider Input "System size" , "connections"

````
  selectInput("mapcomp", "Select Map",
                                    choices = c("system size","connections"),
                                    selected = "system size")
    
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Map

```{r}
pal = colorFactor(palette = c("red","blue", "green"), domain = df$company_name)
````

Then, I connect slider input data with my df. Here I want to use this "filteredData" to loop function to render my map

```
  filteredData <- reactive({
        df[df$type == input$mapcomp,]
      })

renderLeaflet({
  map <- leaflet(df) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addResetMapButton()
```

I am facing problem here.

````
  for(t in unique(filteredData$company_name)){
    sub = filteredData[filteredData$company_name==t,]
map<- map %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
      data=sub,
      lng =  ~ lng,
      lat =  ~ lat,
      radius = 5,
      color =  ~pal(company_name),
      stroke = FALSE, 
      fillOpacity = 0.5,
      group = t)
  
}

    map %>%     
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = unique(df$company_name),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      ) 

})

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

renderPlot({
  ggplot(data=filteredData(),aes(fill=company_name, y=value, x=district)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat= "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue", "green")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip()
})

```
````

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: That error (about `"closure"`) is almost always due to (1) naming your object after a function (common ones: `data` and `df`, both base functions) and then (2) not loading that object into the current environment. Somehow, your definition of `df` is not seen in all code blocks.